# Error en instalando libreria react-infinite-scroll-component

Tags: reactjs, cmd

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de react y cuando trato de instalar la libreria react-infinite-scroll-component en el cmd me da este error, alguien puede decirme que debo de hacer?

ERROR QUE LANZA:
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react-infinite-scroll-component failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org